# starting web app mobile integrating with facebook javascript sdk

Tags: sencha-touch, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm a novice in this topic, I've already have an app in Sencha, now I want to integrate facebook login, I'm studing this facebook tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#register
but I can't understand what is the Mobile Web URL, because my app is in Sencha.

Answer (score 0):

In the ST2 SDK, there is a folder called examples, fine the Jog With Friends app and you can see how to implement facebook